# How to tell if I can send emails from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, email, ubuntu-10.04

I am developing some software using Ruby on Rails in Ubuntu.  I added Ruby's native mailer library, but it isn't sending mails so I want to make sure that my OS is not prohibiting that.

How can I test the ability of my OS to send email?

I got this system output:

```
telnet mx0.gmx.com 25
Trying 74.208.5.90...
Connected to mx0.gmx.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx0.gmx.com GMX Mailservices ESMTP {mx-us011}
EHLO
250-mx0.gmx.com GMX Mailservices
250-8BITMIME
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 SIZE
```

Comment: Any computer with a network connection *can* send mail (if your ISP allows it). Without knowing how Ruby's native mailer library works, it's fairly impossible to answer this question.

Comment: @Hyppy I had in mind the case of maybe being behind a firewall, or having some other security restrictions, or installation quirks.

Comment: `telnet server.com 25` to a valid mail server ... at the prompt type "EHLO". If you get a response, you're good.

Comment: @Hyppy I did this on my own system: "telnet localhost 25" and here is what I got:
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused - what does that mean? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Hyppy: make that an answer.

Comment: @Genadinik: no, you have to telnet to an outside email system that you know works.

Comment: @Ward is there an example of a random one that you know works? Or I can just pick any valid domain name?

Comment: mx0.gmx.com is the mail server for mail.com

Comment: @Hyppy I just posted my complete output in my question.  Not sure how to interpret that - does it mean it works? :)

Comment: If you get a response, you're good.

Comment: I don't know anything about your library, but you may need to install the sendmail utility in ubuntu:  sudo apt-get install sendmail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following command to connect to a valid mail server:

```
telnet server.com 25
```

At the prompt type "EHLO". If you get a response, you're good.

Comment: @Genadinik: the response you posted shows that your system _can_ connect to an external mail server, so there's nothing on your system or between you and that external mail server that's stopping your mail.  Therefore, it's a problem with your software.  QED

Comment: I'll vote up once the new day rolls around in UTC...

Comment: He still could get his mail rejected after EHLO, e.g. if his server IP is blacklisted or something.